# Google Chrome Console Keep after page refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Im using this piece of code to refresh the page and display a message.

`setInterval(function() { alert ("Reloading"),location.reload() },2000);`

How would could I save the code so it continues to run after the refresh?

Comment: An extension might be a better solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to save current variables (current state) to cookie, and after refresh just  loads variables from cookie to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, set up cookies in order for the code to stay up after the refresh